# How to access SwiftUI Metal Shader source code in GPU debug sessions?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shader, metal

I want to step through a simple SwiftUI Metal Shader (a `[[stitchable]]` shader used with [`layerEffect(_:maxSampleOffset:isEnabled:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/layereffect(_:maxsampleoffset:isenabled:))) in the [GPU frame debugger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/metal-debugger).

I set the appropriate build settings, but still:

[image]

Did anyone manage to breakpoint a SwiftUI shader?

Comment: You can't do this right now.

Comment: 

@Spo1ler Thanks for getting back! So it works for "traditional" Metal shaders, but not for the `stitchable` thingies?

Comment: I think it does work with `stitchable`, but not in a way that SwiftUI does it. For it to work with stitchable, every library has to emit debug information. And if your functions are under your control and you can output debug information for the `MTLLibrary` that they come from, if SwiftUI doesn't emit debug info, and I don't think it does, you are out of luck. You could try filing a Feedback Assistant to let Apple engineers know that this is something that you would like to work.